# Template is not included inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I need to include into table a few tr element based on template `prototype/views/prototype/booking/templates/table-row.html`. I use custom directive to indicate the point where template should be inserted. Also I define `rownum` to show what value should be used while pasting template. This just simply don't do anything. How to make it work?

```
prototypeApplication.directive('tablerowtemplate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { rownum:'@' },
        templateUrl: 'prototype/views/prototype/booking/templates/table-row.html'
    };
});
```

**booking**

```
    <table><tr><td>static entry</td></tr>
     <tablerowtemplate rownum="1"></tablerowtemplate>
<tablerowtemplate rownum="2"></tablerowtemplate>
    </table>
```

**prototype/views/prototype/booking/templates/table-row.html**

```
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="form-group first-name">
        <label>First name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-class="{'input-valid': isValidField('FirstName', persons[{{rownum}}].firstName)}"
               name="firstName" class="form-control input-name" ng-model="persons[{{rownum}}].firstName"
               ng-focus="focused('inputFirstName', {{rownum}})"  placeholder="-">
    </div>

</td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE**

No errors in console. All `<tablerowtemplate rownum="1"></tablerowtemplate>` is not excist in html dom when rendered

**UPDATE 2**

When I try to generate a few `cell`s I got only one:

```
            <cell rownum="0"></cell>
            <cell rownum="1"></cell>
            <cell rownum="2"></cell>
            <cell rownum="3"></cell>

prototypeApplication.directive('cell', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
       scope: { rownum:'@' },
        templateUrl: 'prototype/views/prototype/booking/templates/table-row.html'
    };
});
```

Does it mean  that setting `rownum="3"` makes template have {{rownum}} equals 3? Is it possible that value of attribute will tell template what value to inject into itself? How to fix it?

Comment: No error messages in the console ?

Comment: Did you include the template at the page where your ng-app is initialized?

Comment: @arman1991, What do you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought on possible issue that you dind't include your javascript file where your directive is, not html template? (my mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'a an angular issue :(
Read here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

I also tried myself to write a simple directive and the behavior is odd!

Comment: Would `$compile` service make it easier?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't dig deeper in the matter... let me know if you find an effective solution ;)